# How to create SVG's with the stroke property?

Tags: animation, svg, adobe-illustrator, inkscape, stroke

I've been using a combination of Illustrator, Sketch, Inkscape, and Peter Collingridge's [svg-editor](http://petercollingridge.appspot.com/svg-editor) to create and manipulate SVG's, but I've been running into a few issues.  I am trying to create a basic logo using text, and when the logo appears on the page I would like to animate the outside border (with a [drawing effect](https://jakearchibald.com/2013/animated-line-drawing-svg/)), and then fill the centers with a solid color.

In Illustrator and Sketch, I started with a basic text box and converted the layer to outlines, but my exported SVG's only contain a **single** path without the `stroke` and `stroke-width` fields. It just looks something  like this: `<path fill="#FFF" d="…"/>`, with alot of markup in the `d=''` field.

I read up and learned Inkscape exports some of the cleanest SVG's, so imported a PNG of my initials, "traced a bitmap image" and the "ungrouped the layers" per [this demo](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1cZk08x_rAI).  This exported a multi-path svg, but each still lacked the `stroke` and `stroke-width` params.  This is the closest I've come so far to animating it: [codepen.io/pcooney10/pen/PPvGrx](http://codepen.io/pcooney10/pen/PPvGrx), and it also contains the actual SVG code.

I have a few questions, hopefully some people over here can help:

1. How can I create/export SVG's that contain `stroke`, `stroke-width`, `stroke-dasharray`, and `stroke-dashoffset` fields? These params seem to unlock a lot of animation functionality,and my paths only seem to have `fill=''` and `d=''`.
2. Generally, what's the best tool for creating SVG's? It seems Inkscape exports the cleanest SVG code, but it's not as easy to maneuver as Sketch and Illustrator.  Peter Collingridge's svg-editor seems to be the best for slimming down the code, but it doesn't remove all of the styling that Sketch and Illustrator embed in the file.

Comment: This doesn't seem to be a programming problem, advice on tools is off-topic here.

Comment: If you put in garbage, you get out garbage. Try to draw yourself the shapes with inkscape (don't import a bitmap image), or better write yourself the svg code.

Comment: In Illustrator you can set the `stroke`, `stroke-width` and `stroke-dasharray` but you can't set the `stroke-dashoffset` parameter.

Comment: Thank you @elchininet.  Realized after that stroke can be applied to any fill object- it simply just traces a lined around the fill border

Answer (score -2):

You complain of your SVG as containing "d" operations. But this is a powerful notation which draws your letters! You can use this as a start for animation.

Idea: just use Inkscape.

Enter your text. Make it just the way you wish it to appear. Click Menu > Path > Object to Path. This converts it from font-based to vector-based.

Click Save As... and choose the plain SVG format.